# Can I change Scene using JavaFX automatically?

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to make a game as my term final project. So when life level of one player is less or equal zero then I am trying to load another fxml file on the existing stage automatically. But I can't . I am not sure that if-else logic can change one scene to another. It will be helpful if anyone can give a way to change a scene automatically.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ho840.png)
Thanks in advance.

```
if(Controller.lifeDekhao2<=0){
        Parent is = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/FXMLPack/First1.fxml"));
        Scene isScene = new Scene(is);
        Stage window = (Stage) ((Node) (event.getSource())).getScene().getWindow();
        window.setScene(isScene);
        window.show();
        Controller.time_end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
```

Comment: Please include code-snippet you are trying which is not working as expected... its hard to advice only based on goal description.

Comment: @Tan_xe can you provide the stack trace from the console that your are getting? Or provide a description of the error?